# Connecting java and oracle data base

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I am JAVA newbie and I am  trying to connect my java code and oracle database, I followed some tutorial but it did not work. This is my code.

```
  package probasem;



import java.sql.*;

public class Jedan {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","hr","hr");

            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            String sql  = " select * from employees";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                    while (rs.next())
                        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) +  " "  + rs.getInt(2));

con.close();                        
        } catch (Exception e) {


            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

It throws me an exception :
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation

also when I change the local host to 3036 I get this :

java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: Help us help you - share the exception you're getting

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
 and

Comment: I don't see any real issues except non closed statement and result set. So, I am guessing data in either col 1 and 2 is not integer.

Comment: when I change the local host to 3036 I get this : java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: @Alex13 please [edit] your question and paste the entire exception, and indicate what line caused it.

Comment: @Alex13 please describe your employees table what columns it has and what type of those are.

Comment: Problem is not in the url. Its in the data

Comment: I am working on hr scheme - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10771/scripts003.htm

Comment: @GurwinderSingh I am open for suggestions on what should be changes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code to below:

```
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));
```

As second column is firstname and is of type varchar2.

Further, i recommend using column names instead of column position as they make code less error prone like this:

```
rs.getString("firstname");
```

Comment: I copied it and did not remember to change. Thank you very very much!!